# How to get the next text of an XML node, with C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML. Given the classname, I need to get its corresponding colorcode. How can I accomplish this in C# ?
Otherwise said, I have to get to a specific node, given its previous node's text.
Thank you very much

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='template.xslt'?>
<skin name="GHV--bordeaux">
  <color>
    <classname>.depth1</classname>
    <colorcode>#413686</colorcode>
  </color>
  <color>
    <classname>.depth2</classname>
    <colorcode>#8176c6</colorcode>
  </color>...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Load your xml into an XmlDocument and then do:

```
document.SelectSingleNode("/skin/color[classname='.depth1']/colorcode").InnerText
```

Answer (score 5):

With your xml loaded into a document.

```
var color = document.CreateNavigator().Evaluate("string(/skin/color/classname[. = '.depth']/following-sibling::colorcode[1])") as string;
```

This will return one of your color codes, or an empty string.
As @Dolphin notes, the use of following-sibling means that I assume the same element ordering as in the original example.

My Linq version seems slightly more verbose:

```
var classname = ".depth1";
var colorcode = "";

XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);

var code = from color in doc.Descendants("color")
    where classname == (string) color.Element("classname")
    select color.Element("colorcode");

if (code.Count() != 0) {
    colorcode = code.First().Value;
}
```

Comment: This would fail if the order of classname/colorcode is not always the same as in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Xpath would be useful... //skin/color[classname = '.depth1']/colorcode    would return #413686.  Load your xml into a XmlDocument. Then use the .SelectSingleNode method and use the Xpath, changing the classname as needed.

Answer (score 0):

[XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectsinglenode.aspx)  is your solution. There is a pretty good example provided as an example.